# Need help understanding javascript code/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So apparently the following can be used to automate linkedin steps of unfollowing a contact. I tried to run this code in the Chrome Console, and I'm not sure if it works. So I need help from someone who knows Javascript and JQuery to understand what this does, and then I can modify it to make it work.

```
var buttons = $("button"),
interval = setInterval(function(){
    var btn = $('.is-following');
    console.log("Clicking:", btn);
    btn.click();
    if (buttons.length === 0) {
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

PS: The linkedin page that lets to unfollow your contacts is below. Login, and then navigate to the below. 
https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/

Comment: Literally, all those functions you have there can be googled.

Answer (score 0):

First, it selects all the buttons and stores them on the variable buttons ($("TAG") will select elements with the tag TAG). Then, it creates an interval that will be stored in the variable interval (bad practice, btw, because it isn't using "var" to declare the variable, so, it's a global variable, that should be avoided... but it's necessary to declare it as global in order to use clearInterval) that will execute the function inside the setInterval function call every second (1000 ms). That function will get all the elements that have the class "is-following" and will store them on the variable btn. Then, it will log the... buttons? After that, it will execute the click event on all of those buttons. Finally it will check if the amount of buttons are 0. If true, it'll stop the interval.